# Is there a good way to expose store, router, etc in NuxtJs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

Here's an issue. I would like to create an utility file, that works with store. Something like toggling an overlay. Something like
/utils/loading.js:

```js
import { getStore } from '@/utils/store';

export const toggleOverlay = (toggleTo) => {
  const store = getStore();
  store.dispatch('App/toggleOverlay', toggleTo);
}
```

Usually it's an easy task for an SPA. But nuxt threw me for a loop. It seems like there's no good way to do that. All my searches on the internet were fruitless. I'am at my wits end here.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your store or action from vuex into the utility function (as a parameter).

You can access the store with this.$store, or the vuex mapping helpers.

Comment: Here's the rub, i cant create a hierarchy of utility functions that way or i'll have to pass arguments from one to the other. It would muddy the whole chain andstill would make my functions coupled with store/component context.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. It's a bit... clumsy and has a premise that my layouts would contain a component. Anyways, here's a solution, that worked for me:

```js
// dependencyProvider.js
const dependencyProvider = {
  getInstance: null,
  getStore() {
    return this.getInstanceProp('$store');
  },
  getRouter() {
    return this.getInstanceProp('$router');
  },
  getAxios() {
    return this.getInstanceProp('$axios');
  },
  getInstanceProp(propName) {
    if (!this.getInstance) return null;
    const vm = this.getInstance();
    return vm[propName];
  },
};

export default dependencyProvider;

// DependencyProvider.vue
<script>
import dependencyProvider from '@/helpers/dependencyProvider';

export default {
  created() {
    const vm = this;
    const getInstance = () => vm;
    dependencyProvider.getInstance = getInstance;
    Object.seal(dependencyProvider);
  },
  render() {
    return null;
  },
};
</script>
```

If there's more sophisticated method to do that, i would really like to know.